# MAC & iOS Programming

Tags: ios, iphone, macos

Okay, I'm getting into iPhone Apps Development.

I'm short on funds. I can't buy latest MacBook to develop apps on it. I wanna know whether I can buy a old second hand mac book and develop apps on it and publish it on iTunes and there won't be any compatibility issues at all...

OR Can I install latest version of Mac OS X on OLD mac book and still build 100% compatible apps on it.

I'm worried on this thing.

Please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: this is not a technical question. Look for appropriate forums like `superuser`

Comment: "Can I install latest version of iOS on OLD mac book" - you can't install iOS on a Mac...

Comment: To all those down voted my question. This is still a technical forum and my question was still a technical one. I asked it here because here are the experienced programmers and they know each pros and cons of having old vs new macbook. Don't be so rude with newbies. Please get a life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @nikola already said - all you will need is a mac that can still get updates, and an ios device.
but further going: i can just recomend you to buy a mac and ios device that are not too old.

The MAC just for performance becuse as the app gets more complicated - it's build time get longer.

But for iOS: in old devices running new ios versions, they tend to get very limited in functions and also in things you can do with it... not that much of a worry for a development but i can say from my experience with iphone 4 running ios 7 - i understood i need a new iphone... it is inevitable.

Comment: True. However we are talking about a minimal budget. I recommended iPhone4/iPad2 or newer, because they will be able to update to iOS7. You are right about the limitations in functionality though.

Comment: Yes thats kind of true.. but if you used one runnning ios7 you know why i am saying "don't do it!". and they won't get ios8. if he buys one now, it is better to add a couple more bucks and get a 4s that is faster, stronger, and gets more features. and will be good for at least 2 years from now. it's better than buying a new iphone every year just to be able to "just about work".

Answer (score 3):

You do not need the latest Mac model.

A model that is 2-3 years old will do.
Apple support their products with updates, so you will be able to run the latest OSX and Xcode.

You will also need an iOS device, but you do not need the latest one if you do not have the money. an iPhone 4 or iPad 2 will be OK.

Good Luck!

Comment: You don't NEED an ios device, xcode has an iphone and ipad simulator you can test your app on although I would recommend getting a real device sooner or later.

Comment: @JakeSellers you do need an ios device.. you won't be able to upload to the appstore without one connected while uploading it (!)

Comment: @JakeSellers this is true. But if you would want to submit your apps to the App Store it is highly recommended that you test on a real device.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that, Apple why you so silly?

Comment: @JakeSellers because it is profitable....